# Laravel search result is too slow

Tags: ajax, laravel, postgresql

I need to build search functionality in my website. So far I have implemented the query in eloquent. It is like this,

```
`$syukko = Syukko::where('category',  $cat)
->where('status', 1)
->get();`
```

Now, this website may have a large database. My tester tested it and reported that, it was performing too slow. I tried to use paginate to show 20 results per page. Still the speed was not improving.

One colleague suggested me to use AJAX. My question is does AJAX search perform faster than basic eloquent in pgsql? (live search is not necessary)

Also, currently I don't have large database with my machine. I write the code and send it to tester. Can I use any tool to get query time in localhost?

Comment: Can you set indexing on category and status fields on 'Syukko' table, it is store index and searching data faster than now.

Comment: I'll ask if it is possible. If it is possible, what will be the changes in code?

Comment: no, change in database, check link. http://oi65.tinypic.com/8vq4bp.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using ajax won't increase the speed, you need to optimize your query and use it properly to improvise the speed. As @duy Said you can do the indexing to improve the speed.
Laravel Pagination: Default laravel pagination runs **count query** to get the total records, which might take time if you are querying a large database.

You might try a custom pagination will increase the speed.

```
function showSearchR(Request $request){
   $page = (isset($request->page))?$request->page:1;
    $limit = 20;
    $offset = ($page-1)*$limit;
    $syukko = Syukko::where('category',  $cat)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->offset($offset)->limit($limit)
    ->get();
}
```

**To get the query time you can use laravel query log:**
Enable the query log by `DB::enableQueryLog();`
 then use this code after excuting a query `dd(DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: this will not use index

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have to create database index on `category` and `status` in order to increase database performance.

Ajax cannot improve performance a lot, because finally you should use eloquent to access database and return the data.